# APEX: how to get Custom Label's text dynamically?

Tags: apex, customlabel, translation

There is a way to get Custom Label statically in APEX as documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cl_about.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=208.13)

```
System.Label.Label_Name
```

Can I get this label without hardcoding **Label_Name**?

What I've tried so far (and did not work)

```
System.Label.get('Label_Name');
System.Label['elfBCLabel_VAT'];
```

Comment: It's finally available natively from Salesforce . https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_system_label_methods.htm&release=244&type=5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cant get dynamic custom labels in Apex:

Check out this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hhVGAAY)

check out [this](https://kevansfdc.blogspot.in/2017/02/retrieve-salesforce-label-dynamically.html) link has a workaround solution which you can try in VF context:

```
 public static String getLabelString(String labelName ){
    Component.Apex.OutputText output = new Component.Apex.OutputText();
    output.expressions.value = '{!$Label.' + labelName + '}';
    return String.valueOf(output.value);
}
```

Comment: Just be prepared for an Internal Server Error if you try to get a label that doesn't exist... the resulting error is not catchable/blockable.

Comment: @sfdcfox great to know, will keep in mind

Comment: This doesn't work any longer.  You get an error it is restricted to VF Controllers being called from a VF page.